# gradle war task generates META-INF folder in root of war file

Tags: build, war, gradle

My gradle war task seems to generate a META-INF in the root of my war file. Is this a bug in gradle?
AFAIK meta-inf doesnt belong in the root of war files.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin:'war'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
```

Here is my project layout:

[image]

Here is the contents of the war. Notice the META-INF folder

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jar archives, War archives are expected to have a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

PS: Please do not double-post. I already answered your question at http://forums.gradle.org.